# Async function inside .map throws error after first array object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, stripe-payments, array.prototype.map

I am trying to loop through an array to charge a payment to each array object. The function works for the first array object. I am able to see the charge on the stripe side so. The stripe block of code has been tested separately and works without issue.

```
router.post('/test', async (req, res) =>{
  try {
    const newItem = req.body.results;
    return auctions = newItem
        .map(x =>({
          auction_id: x._id.$oid,
          status: x.status,
          bid: x.bidHistory.bid.$numberInt,
          name: x.bidHistory.name,
          user_id: x.bidHistory.user
        }))
        .map(async (y) =>{
          //Perform charge here
          try {
            //Get stripe_id
            const user = await User.findOne({uid: y.user_id})
              if (!user.stripe_id) throw Error("User doesn't have a stripe id");
             
            const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
              amount: y.bid,
              currency: 'usd',
              customer: (user.stripe_id),
              payment_method: (user.stripe_cc),
              off_session: true,
              confirm: true,
            });
    
            res.status(200).json(paymentIntent);
    
          } catch (err) {
            // Error code will be authentication_required if authentication is needed
            console.log('Error code is: ', err.code);        
            const paymentIntentRetrieved = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(err.raw.payment_intent.id);
            console.log('PI retrieved: ', paymentIntentRetrieved.id);
    
            res.status(400).json(paymentIntentRetrieved.id);
          }  
           
        })      
  } catch (err) {        
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }  
})
```

When trying to loop to the second object in the array, I get an error:

```
"Error code is:  undefined
[0] (node:44590) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'payment_intent' of undefined
[0]     at /Users/Alex/Documents/Webdev/mern-nowaitlist/routes/api/stripe.js:151:89"
```

Which is odd because it worked for the first array object. Any clue what's going on here? Do I need to wait before sending another request to stripe?

EDIT 1: I added a promise.all. The loop worked only for the 1st time again. I commented out all the stripe stuff to see what was going on.

```
router.post('/test', async (req, res) =>{
  try {
    const newItem = req.body.results;
    const auctions = newItem
        .map(x =>({
          auction_id: x._id.$oid,
          status: x.status,
          bid: x.bidHistory.bid.$numberInt,
          name: x.bidHistory.name,
          user_id: x.bidHistory.user
        }))
    const results = Promise.all(auctions    
        .map((y) =>{
          //Perform charge here
          
          try {        
            y.bid= y.bid+1;
            res.status(200).json(y.bid)
          } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json(err);
            console.log(err)
          }  
           
        }) 
        )  
       return results    
  } catch (err) {        
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }  
})
```

I now get the following error when trying to run the code:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: Could you include the output of `console.log(err)` after the comment in `catch`?

Comment: The second map is returns an array of promises which need to be resolved. You can wrap it all in a `Promise.all()` call to resolve them before assigning to `auctions` see: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (Though if it's an error in the API call that's a different matter)

Comment: Added promise.all, loop is still stopping at first array object. Now giving me a different error, see edited post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you expect `err.raw` to be, but it appears that `err.raw.payment_intent` is undefined, throwing a new error within your `catch` block.

Try removing the payment intent retrieval and just log the error to see what is failing in the first place, then fix that.

Comment: This is copy paste from stripe's own examples and works fine when not done in an array setup.

Answer (score 0):

The callback you passed to Array.map() returns Promise, so you need to await for it to be resolved by Promise.all. Or loop with a for statement.

Comment: Did that, still not looping to other array items.